# Apache Nifi Create packer<number>temp files in /tmp folder

Tags: apache-nifi, packer

I upgraded version of my nifi cluster (4 nodes) from 1.12 to 1.13 then nifi start to create a lot of files in /tmp folder.
The file's names is in this pattern packer(number)temp .

**example of files:**

packer1000351268325980549temp

packer2431509819824357743temp

The nifi write this file to the disk until is full, and then error (No space left on device) is coming.

what should I do to prevent this files to create ?

**My cluster:**

4 Nodes

Apache Nifi version: 1.13.2

OS: centos 7

*thanks, Tom.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks you use [packer](https://www.packer.io/) in your nifi cluster. Packer creates images and stores them in /tmp. Just reconfigure your packer installation.

Comment: hey Yuri, I did not use any packer in my servers. I only installed Nifi on the servers

Comment: try to run ls -l /tmp/packer* to see user that created the files, probably it will give you a hint what process did it

Comment: I know that the root create this files (root use to run my nifi application) so actually the nifi create this files because only nifi  is installed on this servers